# MVCGrid/MVCForm updating MVCGrid row after updating MVCFord

Tags: atk4

Seems like a simple issue but I can't find the solution.

I have an MVCGrid using an Expander column linked to an MVCForm. I can apply the update easily through the form but I need to refresh MVCGrid after the update. In this case, I am displaying PhysCity in MVCgrid, updating it via the MVCForm and I want that change do be displayed back to the MVCGrid.

Thanks!

Here is what I have:

```
<?php
class page_cview extends Page {
function initMainPage(){

    if(!$this->api->auth->isLoggedIn())$this->api->redirect('/');

    $g=$this->add('MVCGrid');
    $g->setModel('customer_cv',array('custname','Name','PhysAddr1','PhysCity','PhysState'));
    $g->addColumn('expander','details','View/Update');
}
function page_details(){

    //var_dump($_GET);

    $f=$this->add('MVCform');
    $f->setModel('customer_cv')
        ->loadData($_GET['id']);
    $f->addSubmit("Update");

      if($f->isSubmitted()){
        $f->update();
        $this->js()->univ()->successMessage('Saved')->closeExpander()->execute();
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nifty trick which can help you refresh items which you don't have access to the object.

```
$grid->js(true)->addClass('myreload');
$grid->js('myreload')->reload();
```

then anywhere else

```
$this->js()->_selector('.myreload')->trigger('myreload')->execute();
```

This sets a custom event handler to jQuery and then triggers event for the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you romaninsh! I need to dig deeper into jquery.
Here is the updated version of the above ATK4 MVCGrid/MVCForm for everyones use.

```
<?php
class page_cview extends Page {
function initMainPage(){

    if(!$this->api->auth->isLoggedIn())$this->api->redirect('/');

    $g=$this->add('MVCGrid');

    $g->js(true)->addClass('myreload');
    $g->js('myreload')->reload();

    $g->setModel('customer_cv',array('custname','Name','PhysAddr1','PhysCity','PhysState'));
    $g->addColumn('expander','details','View/Update');
}
function page_details(){

    //var_dump($_GET);

    $f=$this->add('MVCform');
    $f->setModel('customer_cv')
        ->loadData($_GET['id']);
    $f->addSubmit("Update");

      if($f->isSubmitted()){
        $f->update();
        $this->js()
            ->_selector('.myreload')->trigger('myreload')
            ->univ()
                ->successMessage('Saved')
                ->closeExpander()->execute();
        }
}
}
```