# How to refresh grid after update from modal form in atk4?

Tags: atk4

I have a page with a MVCGrid calling a modal form from external page:

```
$g1=$p->add('MVCGrid');
$g1->setModel('Student');
$g1->addButton('Add New') 
   ->js('click')
   ->univ()
   ->dialogURL('Add New', $this->api->getDestinationURL('newStudent'));
```

The external page has the form and works fine:

```
$f=$page->add('MVCForm');
$f->setModel('Student');
if($f->isSubmitted()){
    $f->update();
    $f->js()->univ()->closeDialog()->execute();
}
```

But after a new Student is added, the grid is not updated, how do I update it?
Is this this the right way to do this?
(I'm trying to have a similar function that the CRUD but only for Create.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/8966784/204819

put the refresh code as 2nd argument to js() function, while using "null" as first.

Comment: I already tried that o that fiel, but now the window does not close. I can either close it or refresh the grid, but not both...

Comment: got it worked thanks! $this->js(null,$this->js()->_selector('.myreload')->trigger('myreload'))
                ->univ()           
                ->closeDialog()
                ->successMessage('Actualizado')                
                ->execute();