# highlighting/selecting a specific tab after submitting search form

Tags: atk4

I'm wondering if there is a way in atk 4.2 to have a specific tab selected based on
what search results where found after submitting a search form.

if have a simple search form (searching for keywords or criteria given by the user)
that updates a number of GRIDs each under its own tab.
these GRIDs get updated after the user submits the form, as mentioned here: [Implementing a search form that updates grid or lister](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473669/implementing-a-search-form-that-updates-grid-or-lister)

now when a grid has no search results, it says 'no records found' which is a bit confusing for the user, and it would be better to automatically show the user a grid which does have search results...

the idea would be to select the first tab with a grid that has results, and possibly hide tabs for grids that returned empty search results, is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this - maybe it's useful for you.

```
/**
 * Set specific tab as selected
 * $id  is zero-based index of the tab to be selected or the id selector
 *      of the panel the tab is associated with (the tab's href fragment
 *      identifier, e.g. hash, points to the panel's id).
 */
function setSelect($id){
    $this->js(true)->tabs('select',$id);
}
```

You can extend /atk4/lib/View/Tabs/jUItabs.php with this new method or simply use one line JS yourself.

Comment: Correction: I believe this method will not be implemented in ATK4 Tabs class as shown above. More likely it'll be implemented as $tabs->setOption('selected',$id); where $id is zero-based index of active tab.
You should check Github and see in jUItabs.php for yourself in next few days.

Comment: One more correction. Now this is possible with following command:

$tabs->setOption('active',$id); where $id is zero-based index of active tab.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that's possible, but with event triggering it might be difficult to pass the search criteria.

1. Create a page 'my/search'
2. Add search form `$form=..`
3. Add tabs `$tabs=..`
4. When form is submitted, you will need to reload tabs:

   if($form->isSubmitted()){
       $q=$form->get('search');
       $tabs->js()->reload(array('q'=>$q))->execute();
   }

5 Next populate the tabs, but you need to get the results first.

```
$tab1_data = $this->add('Model_Data1');
$tab1_data ->addCondition('name','like','%'.$_GET['q'].'%');
$tab1_count = $tab1_data->count()->getOne();
if($tab1_count){
    $tabs->addTab('Data1 ('.$tab1_count.')')
        ->add('CRUD')->setModel($tab1_data);
}
```

You might need to have a check and add at least one tab if no results were found just to show the message. You can also use the count inside the tab, quite handy.

Comment: hi, yes... this would be fine if I'd be using Models but for flexibility reasons I'm currently using GRIDs with setSource() and using ->dq->where() after the form submit to apply the 'q' query params you mentioned. so I'm somewhat limited to:                   ` $tabs=$this->add('Tabs');
$conf=$tabs->addTab('Conflictos');        $gconf=$conf->add('Grid');      $gconf->addColumns()               if (isset($_GET["q"]) $gconf->dq->where(something with $q)   `                       So I was wondering it there was any easy way to do   GRID->Hide()or GRID->Selectme() or something like that ?

Comment: well you could do this: `$q2=clone $q; $q2->del('fields'); $q2->field('count(*)'); $cnt=$q2->getOne();`